# Set the value of a AbstractControl in ReactiveForm (Angular) in a Jasmine unit test

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-reactive-forms

How to set the value of a AbstractControl in ReactiveForm in a Jasmine unit test?

**My form:**

```
this.formChangePassword = this.formBuilder.group({
  username: ['', [Validators.required]],
  oldpassword: ['', [Validators.required]],
  passwords: this.formBuilder.group({
    newpassword: ['', [Validators.required]],
    confirmpassword: ['', [Validators.required]]
  }, {validator: this.passwordConfirming})
});
```

**My mock in jasmine unit test:**

```
component.formChangePassword.controls.username.setValue('foo'); <= is OK
component.formChangePassword.controls.passwords.controls.newpassword.setValue('newpwd'); <= is KO
```

I looking for write `newpwd` in `newpassword` `AbstractControl`

```
component.formChangePassword.controls.passwords ?? newpassword.setValue('newpwd');
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what you mean by "is KO"?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Read the documentation of FormGroup, especially the documentation of `patchValue` and of  `get()`.